# Bison Shift/Reduce conflicts for small language parser

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

My objective is to create a parser for a small language.  It is currently giving me one shift/reduce error.

My CFG is ambiguous somewhere, but I can't figure out where

```
prog:    PROGRAM beg                   {$$ = "program" $2;}
    |   PROGRAM stmt beg               {$$ = "program" $2 $3;}

beg:    BEG stmt END                   {$$ = "begin" $2 "end";}
    | BEG END                      {$$ = "begin" "end";}


stmt:   beg             {$$ = $1;}
    | if_stmt                   {$$ = $1;}/*
    | IF expr THEN stmt                 {$$ = $1 $2 $3 $4;}*/
    | WHILE expr beg                    {$$ = "while" $2 $3;}
    | VAR COLEQUALS arithexpr SEMI      {$$ = $1 ":=" $3 ";";}
    | VAR COLON INTEGER SEMI            {$$ = $1 ":" "integer" ";";} /*Declaring an integer */
    | VAR COLON REAL SEMI               {$$ $1 ":" "real" ";";}   /*declaring a real */

if_stmt:  IF expr THEN stmt            {$$ = "if" $2 "then" $4;}
    | IF expr THEN stmt ELSE stmt      {$$ = "if" $2 "then" $4 "else" $6;}

expr:   NOT VAR                        {$$ = "!" $2;}
| VAR GREATERTHAN arithexpr        {$$ = $1 ">" $3;}
    | VAR LESSTHAN arithexpr           {$$ = $1 "<" $3;}
    | VAR GREATERTHANEQUALTO arithexpr {$$ = $1 ">=" $3;}
    | VAR LESSTHANEQUALTO arithexpr    {$$ = $1 "<=" $3;}
    | VAR EQUALS arithexpr             {$$ = $1 "==" $3;}
    | VAR NOTEQUALS arithexpr          {$$ = $1 "!=" $3;}
    | arithexpr AND arithexpr          {$$ = $1 "&&" $3;}
    | arithexpr OR arithexpr           {$$ = $1 "||" $3;}


arithexpr:  arithexpr PLUS term            {$$ = $1 + $3;}
    |  arithexpr MINUS term            {$$ = $1 - $3;}
    |   term                   {$$ = $1;}

term:   term TIMES factor          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
    | term DIVIDE factor           {$$ = $1 / $3;}
    | factor               {$$ = $1;}

factor:   VAL                              {$$ = $1;}
```

Comment: Doesn't Bison give you any clues in the error message as to where the conflict is?

Comment: It only tells you how many conflicts you have, not where they are. 

Errors on the other hand are given to you

Comment: Use the `-v` option to get a `.output` file showing where and what the conflicts are...

Answer (score 1):

The "error" comes from the ambiguity in the `if`_stmt's `else` part: `stmt` can be an if_stmt, and it's not clear to which if a else-part belongs, e.g. if you write:

```
if y1 then if y2 then x=1 else x=2
```

Then the else-part could either belong to the first if or the second one.

This question has been asked in variations many times, just search for `if then else shift reduce`

For diagnosis (to find out that you are also a victim of that `if then else shift reduce` problem) you can tell bison to produce an output-file with

```
bison -r all  myparser.y
```

which will produce a file myparser.output, in which you can find for your case:

```
State 50 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
....
state 50

   11 if_stmt: IF expr THEN stmt .  [ELSE, BEG, END]
   12        | IF expr THEN stmt . ELSE stmt

    ELSE  shift, and go to state 60

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 11 (if_stmt)]
    $default  reduce using rule 11 (if_stmt)


state 51
...
```

One solution for this would be to introduce a block-statement and only alow these as statements in the if and else part:

```
stmt: ...
    | blk_stmt
blk_stmt: BEGIN stmt END
if_stmt:  IF expr THEN blk_stmt
    | IF expr THEN blk_stmt ELSE blk_stmt
```

Which would for a modified c-language mean that only

```
if x1 then {if x2 then {y=1}} else {y=2}
```

be possible (with `{` representing the BEGIN-token and `}`representing the END-token) thus resolving the ambiguity.